# Frame navigation in xaml return false

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, navigation

Hello,
I'm working in a simple Windows 8 application with xaml and c#. I'm using the VS 2012 templates to create pages, with navigation system included.

I'm loading a lot of data, so I decided to add a loading page with a ProgressRing and navigate to the first Application page when loading data is finished:

`//loading page

 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
...

await topCookerManager.GetBlogsAsync();

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

...
}`

It works well when application is starting, but when I'm on the first page of application and when I'm click on back button I'm redirect to the loading page. So, in the loading page I'm checking if data are loaded and if yes I redirect to the first page.

`if (dataManager.Blogs != null && dataManager.Blogs.Count > 0)

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));`

**That's the problem**: I' can't navigate from this point. The Navigate method return false ! I've tested *GoFormard* method, it throw no exception but navigation is not done and I'm staying on the loading page...

Could you please tell me where is my mistake ? Or how implement a loading page.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you have used a page to show "loading" ? You can have dark filled border with centered progress ring which covers the entire screen. when data is loaded hide that border and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Ok, it's a solution. If I can't solve my problem and understand why it doesn't work, I will use this action.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't `Navigate` from within the `OnNavigatedTo` method as the previous navigation method is still executing at that point. Instead, you can wait for it to be loaded by running the new navigation call via a dispatcher.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     //your other code
     //...
     Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                            () => Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage))); 
}
```

The reason why it may work the first time in your code is because you're waiting for a few moments for the blogs to load. Within this time, the navigation method has completed loading and so it can be called again.

Having said that, consider if you really wanting a loading page and not just an overlay of some sort as Xyroid mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much, saved my whole day. Just I added 'await' before Dispatcher, which then runs very well.