# Frame.Navigate in LoadState

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm having trouble trying to navigate automatically between pages in my Windows 8.1 app based on a little check. It just doesn't want to navigate to another page when doing this in `LoadState`, as if something isn't loaded yet, but it doesn't give an error either. When I insert a delay using (for example) `await Task.Delay(2000)` before doing `Frame.Navigate`, then my app will redirect without any problem.

```
protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        MyData oData = await getData();

        if (oData != null)
        {
             this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(newPage), oData);
        }
        else
        {
             // do something else
        }

    }
```

Do I have to put this code in another load- or navigated-event? Or how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `LoadState` and `SaveState` you should only save and restore the page state (called when suspending and reactivating the app). Do nothing else (like navigating).

Put your logic into the `OnNavigatedTo` method instead...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate from method that called when page is loads, you should place your navigation code to OnNavigatedTo(...). But do not forget to wrap your code in Dispatcher.RunAsync(...) - [Frame navigation in xaml return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739996/frame-navigation-in-xaml-return-false)

Answer (score 0):

I tried calling Frame.Navigate(...) from the **OnNavigatedTo** method but still the navigation didn't occur.

There are other answers which say use **Dispatcher.RunAsync**, but that feels like it's making assumptions about the threading model of Windows Phone.

Here's what I do: attach a handler to the **Loaded** event of the page instead, and put my "redirect" logic in there. Loaded fires after OnNavigateTo and after NavigationHelper_LoadState, but before the page has become visible.

```
    public LaunchPadPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

        this.Loaded += LaunchPadPage_Loaded;

        this.app = (App)App.Current;
    }

    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e) {
        // Let's show the root zone items
        // NB: In case we don't have this data yet, do nothing
        if (app.Hierarchy != null)
        {
            DefaultViewModel["Items"] = app.Hierarchy.RootItems;
        }
    }

    private void LaunchPadPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // No data? Go to the downloads page instead.
        if (app.Hierarchy == null)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(DownloadingPage));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `NavigationHelper`?