# Canceling navigation in Page.OnNavigatingFrom with MessageBox

Tags: navigation, winrt-async

I have a two-page WinRT application, where the first navigates to the second. I want to ask the user in `OnNavigatingFrom` if he really wants to navigate to the second, via a message box. The navigation cancelation is done by setting `.Cancel=true` of `eventargs`... that I can do AFTER the message box finishes.

My problem is that `MessageDialog.ShowAsync` is an asynchronous method.

1.
Cannot do `.AsTask().Result`... that causes deadlock of course.

2.
Cannot use `await`, because the `OnNavigatingFrom` is `void`, so making it async causes the caller to return immediately when I do await `ShowAsync().AsTask().Result`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to cancel a navigation asynchronously from the OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) event handler.

If you want to prevent the user from navigating away, you will have to display your dialog box before requesting the navigation.

```
var dialog          = new MessageDialog("Navigate away ?");
var okCommand       = new UICommand("OK");
var cancelCommand   = new UICommand("Cancel");
dialog.Commands.Add(okCommand);
dialog.Commands.Add(cancelCommand);

var result  = await dialog.ShowAsync();
if(result == okCommand)
{
    (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I've found a way to do it, It's based off of these two answers:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78ba6d55-dd67-4e56-b9f1-137fc6a1e1a7/how-to-block-the-navigation-with-alert?forum=winappswithcsharp
- [Frame navigation in xaml return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739996/frame-navigation-in-xaml-return-false)

Essentially, what you do is you cancel by default, then you show your dialog box, and then, if it's okay to navigate, you set a flag that prevents you from setting cancel to true, and then you re-navigate to the page.

In it's simplest form, it looks like this.

```
bool _navigabile = false;
protected async override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_navigabile)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        var result = true;// await MessageDialog.ShowAsync(/*...*/)

    if (result)
        {
            _navigabile = true;
            var current = Window.Current;
            var frame = current.Content as Frame;

            var ignore = current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () => frame.Navigate(e.SourcePageType, e.Parameter));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your first condition should be `if (!_navigable)` instead of `if (_navigable)` but otherwise it seems to work.